# Iterating over separate lists in R

Tags: r, list, loops

I have lots of variables in R, all of type list

```
a100 = list()
a200 = list()
# ...
p700 = list()
```

Each variable is a complicated data structure:

```
a200$time$data # returns 1000 x 1000 matrix
```

Now, I want to apply code to each variable in turn. However, since R doesn't support pass-by-reference, I'm not sure what to do.

One idea I had was to create a big list of all these lists, i.e.,

```
biglist = list()
biglist[[1]] = a100
...
```

And then I could iterate over biglist:

```
for (i in 1:length(biglist)){
    biglist[[i]]$newstuff = "profit"
    # more code here
}
```

And finally, after the loop, go backwards so that existing code (that uses variable names) still works:

```
a100 = biglist[[1]]
# ...
```

The question is: is there a better way to iterate over a set of named lists? I have a feeling that I'm doing things horribly wrong. Is there something easier, like:

```
# FAKE, Idealized code:
foreach x in (a100, a200, ....){
    x$newstuff = "profit"
}

a100$newstuff # "profit"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To parallel walk over lists you can use mapply, which will take parallel lists and then walk over them in lock-step. Furthermore, in a functional language you should emit the object that you want rather than modify the data structure within a function call.

You should use the sapply, apply, lapply, ... family of functions.

jim

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts jim. How can I use lapply, and still modify the original lists? For example, if I did `lapply(biglist, function(x){x$newstuff = "profit"; x})`, the original `biglist` wouldn't be modified, would it? Each `x` would just be output to the screen, not saved anywhere?

Comment: Jim - After thinking about it some more, I've decide that your advice to emit the object, rather than modify the object, is golden. Much better to structure my code as `a100 = computeStuff(a100)` than all the complication I was thinking of. Thanks for this advice.

Answer (score 1):

jimmyb is quite right. `lapply` and `sapply` are specifically designed to work on lists. So they would work with your biglist as well. You shouldn't forget to return the object in the nested function though : An example :

```
X <- list(A=list(A1=1:2,A2=3:4),B=list(B1=5:6,B2=7:8))

lapply(X,function(i){
    i$newstuff = "profit"
    return(i)
})
```

Now as you said, R passes by value so you have multiple copies of the data roaming around. If you work with really big lists, you might want to try toning the memory usage down by working on each variable seperately, using `assign` and `get`. The following is considered bad coding, but can sometimes be necessary to avoid memory trouble :

```
A <- X[[1]] ; B <- X[[2]] #make the data
list.names <- c("A","B")

for (i in list.names){
    tmp <- get(i)
    tmp$newstuff <- "profit"
    assign(i,tmp)
    rm(tmp)
}
```

Make sure you are well aware of the implication this code has, as you're working within the global environment. If you need to do this more often, you might want to work with environments instead :

```
my.env <- new.env() # make the environment
my.env$A <- X[[1]];my.env$B <- X[[2]] # put vars in environment

for (i in list.names){
    tmp <- get(i,envir=my.env)
    tmp$newstuff <- "profit"
    assign(i,tmp,envir=my.env)
    rm(tmp)
}
my.env$A
my.env$B
```